# Get Referer URL in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, referer

How can I get the referer URL in Spring MVC Controller?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's available as HTTP request header with the name `referer` (yes, with the misspelling which should have been `referrer`).

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
// ...
```

Here the `request` is the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) which is available in Spring beans in several ways, among others by an `@AutoWired`.

Please keep in mind that this is a client-controlled value which can easily be spoofed/omitted by the client.

Comment: Thanks I was doing that and forgot I was on the homepage and that is why it was always the base url.  I will need to parse for the host name in the referer on inner page with a longer url.  I am comparing IP and Hostname.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why the referer is null?

Comment: That can happen if the page was requested by directly entering the URL in address bar or by a bookmark.

Answer (score 44):

In Spring MVC 3 you can get it from request, as @BalusC already said:

```
public ModelAndView doSomething(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
    ...
}
```

but there also exists special annotation [@RequestHeader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader) which allow to simplify your code to

```
public ModelAndView doSomething(@RequestHeader(value = "referer", required = false) final String referer) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  Only one thing to note is that I had to use a capital R in Referer.

Comment: @steven-dix Header name should be case insensitive because Spring uses `HttpServletRequest.getHeaders()` where "the header name is case insensitive" (quote from API) And it also works for me. Anyway thanks for sharing this, probably, in some environment this will help to someone.

Comment: You can use [HttpHeaders.REFERER](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#REFERER) constant instead of hardcoding `referer`.