# How to no redirect to another page when user logout in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring security for logout page. when user access and view product detail page, user continues to click logout, and then it will redirect to home page, it work fine !
this is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }

    return "redirect:/homepage";
}
```

However I want when user logout, user still access current page(product detail page) and no need it redirect to homepage

How to fix the problem ? Thank so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the referrer of the logout request and use it in your return redirect statement.

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
return "redirect:" + referrer
```

Here are some implementations to get the referrer:
[Get Referer URL in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588907/get-referer-url-in-spring-mvc)